# How can I use a service account to authenticate with Azure AD using OAuth2.0

Tags: rest, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, onedrive

I'm developing a Web API that needs create, read, update and delete privileges on OneDrive for Business sites using REST.

So far my understanding is that an Azure Application will need to be registered within Azure for this 
WebAPI.

Once registered the Application will have a client ID and secret key that can be used as part of OAuth. Also within Azure it can also be given the permission to call the SharePoint 365 API. (Provided the authenticated user is also authorized).

MSDN has code examples in which using the Application client ID within OAuth the client gets redirected to a login page for authentication. Once they enter in their username and password they are redirected back to the web application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn646737.aspx

As I am developing a web API I do not want any redirects to login pages. Instead I would like to automatically authenticate using a service account. (Which will have appropriate permissions within the OneDrive for Business site).

Does anyone know how this can be done or point me in the direction of some code samples?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Service to Service (app only) grants aren't possible today for SharePoint with AzureAD OAuth. We only allow app + user grants.

This is on our radar - please stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks Dushyant, but am I not correct in thinking that the service account would be the user? The only difference is that this service account needs to  authenticate automatically by providing a username and password instead of being redirected to a login page. Its similar to example NativeClient-Headless-DotNet on github samples however i want to call SharePoint 365 API once authenticated.